# Any limit on the number of projects for using visual studio online

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Are there any limitations on the number of projects within Visual Studio online? When I go to the [Azure Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/), all the calculations for the visual studio online are based on the number of users not the number of projects. Lets say if I have 5 users (which will be free) with 10 projects or 200 projects, it should not matter in terms of the pricing, right?

Comment: Well on their [home page](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) it says *Unlimited free private repos*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licensing.

Comment: @Daniel Mann, if you don't know the answer just don't bother posting something. What might sound something trivial or pointless in your view might be a very important question for someone else.

Comment: @MHOOS It's not a matter of knowing the answer, it's a matter of whether a topic is on-topic or not. For what it's worth, the licensing is based on number of users, not projects. Costs can change depending on what services you use and how you use them (build, release, etc).

Comment: @MHOOS What do you think of my solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main kinds of storage that you use:

1. Blob store – this is the size of the files, attachments, etc that are stored on the service.  The files are compressed so that affects the size.  The blob store is, for all intents and purposes unlimited (though we may from time to time impose limits to prevent abuse).  Legitimate use is basically unlimited.
2. Meta-data store – Metadata (version control version info, work item records, test execution results, etc) are stored in a SQL Azure database and SQL Azure has raised their max database size, also the data will be compressed, so you don’t need to worry about it.

More information, you can refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2013/11/20/how-much-data-can-you-put-on-vsonline/) article. About Azure SQL Database resource limits, you can refer to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-resource-limits/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio online offers unlimited number of projects and the license depends on the number of users, with 5 users free of charge.